# jquery Tab navigation with Tabkey

Tags: jquery, html, tabpanel

I am using JQuery UI Tabs. I need to be able to navigate from 1st to 2nd tab and then 2nd to 3rd using the tab key. I have a few links on the first tab.
Currently, when I hit tab-key it takes me from 1st tab to the links within the 1st tab, instead I want it to go to the 2nd tab

Code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">   
$(function () {
$("#tabs").tabs({
    activate: function() {
        var selectedTab = $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'active');
        $('#<%= hdnSelectedTab.ClientID %>').val(selectedTab);
    },
     active: document.getElementById('<%= hdnSelectedTab.ClientID %>').value
});


});
</script> 
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnSelectedTab" Value="0" />
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">All training</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">By location</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Search</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
     /* Control */
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="LocationsPanel" />
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
    <p>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="SearchTextBox" class="long" aria-label="Search Training Courses"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;<asp:Button runat="server" ID="SearchButton" Text="Search" OnClick="SearchButton_Click" CssClass="lessfocus" />
    </p>  
</div>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

What am I missing here? Please help

Comment: use tabindex attribute  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

Comment: I did use the tabindex attribute to the anchor tag but the generated HTML simply ignores it and sets the tabindex to -1

Comment: right and you need to set tabindex on the content also